# Yelp API key not working in Sencha Architect demo code

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am using the tutorial here : http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/tutorials/first_mobile_application.html#The_Controller

```
getBusinesses: function(location, callback) {
    // Note: Obtain a Yelp API key by registering (for free)
    // with Yelp at http://www.yelp.com/developers/getting_started/api_overview
    // (in this app, we use the Review Search API v1.0)

    var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('BusinessStore'),
        yelpKey = '', // Enter your Yelp API key here
        url = 'http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search' +
        '?ywsid=' + yelpKey +
        '&term=Bars' +
        '&lat=' + location.coords.latitude +
        '&long=' + location.coords.longitude;

    store.getProxy().setUrl(url);


    store.load(function() {
        callback(store);
    });
}
```

I applied for an API key on Yelp and got the following:

[image: Yelp API Keys]

I am not sure which one to use. The tutorial code has placeholder for one single key as in the code above

The completed app shows error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStore' of undefined at:

```
        me.getBusinesses(location, function (store) {

            // Bind data to the list and display it
            me.getDataList().setStore(store);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need the API v1.0 key.
2. `getDataList()` returns undefined because the **View** does not exist. You may have forgotten to name the **List** view in the **ListContainer**, see *"List View - Step 4"*. Also, the function name is derived from whatever you set the reference to in *"The Controller - Step 7". Naming it `datalist` will make the function `getDatalist()`, whereas naming it `dataList` will make it `getDataList()`. Note the capital "L".

Hope this helps others running into the problem.